# Use both api and web guard in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I want my laravel application to be used as a rest api but also as a normal website. The problem is that I can't do both as default authentication and i need this two guards that my application work.

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

When i add both my form on the page does not work

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

Comment: the `auth` middleware itself takes arguments so you could pass both guards to it and it will cycle through them until it gets a user and set that as the default guard for the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @lagbox mentioned you can do it like this

```
Route::middleware('auth:web,api')->get('/', function(Request $request){
    return $request->user();
});
```

but I always try to avoid putting the web guards and api guards together.

because the laravel default auth middleware will finally redirect to login url if all the guards failed to get user, so you must rewrite this middleware if you want's it to return json.

try to change the App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate class like this, it should work.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        try {
            $this->authenticate($request, $guards);
        } catch(AuthenticationException $e){
            return response()->json([
                //custom your response here                
            ]);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```